# Двойная итерация в одном цикле

Tags: c++, c, циклы

Как сделать так, чтобы одновременно в одном цикле шли две итерации (например `i` и `j`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Так сойдет? :)

```
for(int i = 5, j = 10; i < 20 && j >= 0; i++, j--)
{
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Вы можете объявить в теле цикла сколько угодно переменных

```
for (int i = 0, j = 100; i != j; ++i, --j) {
  //SOME CODE;
}
```

Или вы можете использовать вложенные циклы

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    //SOME CODE
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        //SOME CODE
    }
}
```

Так же можно использовать цикл while в разном виде

```
int i = 0;
int j = 50;
while (true) {
   --i;
   ++j;
   if (i == j) {
      break;
   }
   //SOME CODE
}
```

Выбор зависит лишь от поставленной задачи и личных предпочтений.